# Python Windows service

Tags: python-3.x, windows, ctypes

I am working on using the Windows API to build a service. I have already tested and used the win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework module yet I am trying to get around using a 3rd party import.

I have the following so far:

```
LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_wchar_p)

class SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('ServiceName', ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ('ServiceProc', LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW)]

def test():
    logging.info('Test is running')

service_process = LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW(test)
service_table = SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW(ServiceName='Test_Service', ServiceProc=service_process)
ctypes.windll.advapi32.StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW(service_table)
```

However when calling StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW I get the following error back:

> ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments

If anyone could provide some assistance or direction it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The `LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW` callback is defined as:

```
typedef VOID (WINAPI *LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW)(
    DWORD   dwNumServicesArgs,
    LPWSTR  *lpServiceArgVectors
    );
```

Which is:

```
LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p))
```

or if using `ctypes.wintypes`:

```
from ctypes import WINFUNCTYPE,POINTER
from ctypes import wintypes as w

LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW = WINFUNCTYPE(None, w.DWORD, POINTER(w.LPWSTR))
```

Note the first parameter to `WINFUNCTYPE` is the return type and the second parameter to the callback is a `LPWSTR*` not a `LPWSTR`.

Comment: Also, to head off future problems, the OP should stop using the shared `ctypes.windll` library loader, which can lead to conflicting prototype definitions with other packages and doesn't preserve the thread's last error value around an FFI call. Instead use `advapi32 = ctypes.WinDLL('advapi32.dll', use_last_error=True)`. Get the last error code when an API call fails with `ctypes.get_last_error()`, and usually raise an exception via `raise ctypes.WinError(error_code)`.